# Wildcard Consume javax.ws.rs

Tags: java, media-type, javax.ws.rs

Would like to accept all requests independent on the `Content-Type` set in header.

As an example a `Content-Type` can be `application/json`. By then setting:

```
@Consumes(MediaType.WILDCARD)
```

Will respond: `HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type`

But if the consume is defined as a list with multiple items:

```
@Consumes({ MediaType.WILDCARD, MediaType.APPLICATION_SVG_XML })
```

The request is accepted: `200 OK`

Any ideas why not the `MediaType.WILDCARD` accepts `application/json`?

Edit: Running `javax.ws.rs-api-2.1.jar`

Comment: Sounds like a bug. What implementation are you using? And BTW, you can just remove the annotation altogether

Comment: @ernest_k said it all, but btw: `@Consumes({ MediaType.WILDCARD })` one could try too.

Comment: @ernest_k Running javax.ws.rs-api-2.1.jar. By removing the `@Consume` I get the same problem where it only accepts requests when `Content-Type` is not defined.
@Joop Eggen Same problem there.